# How do I solve this error "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The `setSpeedX` was underlined for the error "not all code paths return a value". May I know how do I solve it? The codes are as below:

```
class Ball
{
    public int speedX { get; private set; }
    public int speedY { get; private set; }
    public int positionX { get; private set; }
    public int positionY { get; private set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
    {
        speedX = newSpeedX;
    }    

    public int setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
    {
        speedY = newSpeedY;
    }

    public int setPositionX(int newPositionX)
    {
        positionX = newPositionX;
    }

    public int setPositionY(int newPositionY)
    {
        positionY = newPositionY;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: why you set property as `private set`?

Comment: What is the thinking behind using `setX` methods to set the property rather than making the property setter public?

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you just expose your public properties.?Setters which return values may [violate CQS](http://andreasohlund.net/2008/09/04/command-query-separation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a value in your methods (`setSpeedX`, `setSpeedY`, `setPositionX`, `setPositionY` ), but not returning anything. But the signature of the methods have a return type `int`.

So... replace the return type `int` with `void`, like this:

```
public void setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
}    

public void setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
{
    speedY = newSpeedY;
}

public void setPositionX(int newPositionX)
{
    positionX = newPositionX;
}

public void setPositionY(int newPositionY)
{
    positionY = newPositionY;
}
```

or return a value of type `int`, like this:

```
public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
    return speedX;
}    

public int setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
{
    speedY = newSpeedY;
    return speedY;
}

public int setPositionX(int newPositionX)
{
    positionX = newPositionX;
    return positionX;
}

public int setPositionY(int newPositionY)
{
    positionY = newPositionY;
    return positionY;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `return` to your methods that should return value like:

```
public int setPositionY(int newPositionY)
{
    positionY = newPositionY;
    return positionY;
}
```

or change them to return `void`:

```
public void setPositionY(int newPositionY)
{
    positionY = newPositionY;
}
```

Comment: @Guang If you find this answer most helpful, please mark it as a solution. Also, why noone in this post used shorter version: return positionY = newPositionY?

Comment: @slawekwin because it is not as readable, it can easily be misunderstood as `positionY == newPositionY`. Readability is very important in code.

Answer (score 1):

You never put a `return` statement, so no value is returned, even though you declare the method that it should.

There are two ways to fix this:

make the method `void`:

```
public void setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
}
```

or return a value:

```
public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
    return speedX;
}
```

This goes for all methods by the way, not just `setSpeedX`.

Answer (score 0):

Either return a value

```
public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
    return(speedX);
}
```

Or change the method to void

```
public void setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
    speedX = newSpeedX;
}
```

There doesn't seem to be much value in returning a value